# How can remove the bottom shadow of UINavigationBar?

Tags: uinavigationbar

I am using custom navigationBar within my projects, but it's giving bottom drop shadow of UINavigation bar, How we can remove it, Please provide the answer for it if any work on it.

TIA :)

Comment: just a guess, try setting clipsToBounds to YES on your navigation bar object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to remove the shadow underneath the `UINavigationBar` is to set a custom background image and then set the shadow image to a blank `UIImage`.

**CustomViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

In the above example, "Background" would be a PNG image in your project.

Answer (score 1):

in iOS7:

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
     for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
            if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                if (view2.frame.size.height < 1) {
                    [view2 removeFromSuperview];
                }
         }
      }
 }
```